# Collider waiting for two differently tagged game objects to enter before doing something

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've got a collider that's checking for the tag of the game object that enters it. If both a green and ref tag enter it I want to call a separate function.

I have it working for individual game objects but I'm having problems with multiple. This is all happening inside a OnTriggerEnter2D.

I'm not getting any errors with it but the debug.long never prints so the collider isn't seeing the gameobjects.

Thanks in advance! :)

```
        else if (trigCol.name == "Yellow Trigger")
        {
            if ((collision.CompareTag("greenBlock")) && (collision.CompareTag("redBlock")))    //  If the tag of the colliding object is greenBlock
            {
                Debug.Log("Inside yellow trigger. This is the " + collision.tag + " tag");
                YellowBlock();
            }
            else if (collision.tag == "blueBlock")
            {
                Debug.Log("Incorrect block!");
                wrongSound.Play();
                currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
                SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Trigger callbacks happen one trigger at a time, so you need to track the redblocks/greenblocks in a variable in your monobehavior.  You can either save the blocks in Lists, or increment/decrement a counter for each color when they leave or enter the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collision`is only one value, the `OnCollisionEnter`function gets called each time there is a collision.

Try using variables that are set in `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` to keep track of when two objects are both colliding with the referenced object.